# Liferay : How to get user profilePicURL without ThemeDisplay in serviceImpl classes?

Tags: java, web-services, null, liferay, user-profile

I want to get a user's profilePicURL in a web-service call.

I just have a userId of that User.

This is what I am trying

```
public String getProfilePicURL(long userId) throws SystemException,
        PortalException {
    String url = "";

    ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextThreadLocal
            .getServiceContext();
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = serviceContext.getThemeDisplay();

    User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);

    try {
        url = user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay);
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return url;
    }
}
```

When I did `System.out.println(themeDisplay)`, it came out as `null`

I don't know any other way of achieving this.

What should I change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use`UserConstants.getPortraitURL(imagePath, male, portraitId);` 
from [UserConstants](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-service/6.2.3/com/liferay/portal/model/UserConstants.java#UserConstants.getPortraitURL%28java.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Clong%29) class of liferay.

Comment: Thanks Devz,

Can you please tell me what is imagePath here?
I don't know what to be passed there.

Thanks

Comment: It is "/image".

Comment: Hi Devz,

That I understood.
And I tried `themeDisplay.getPathImage()` , but it goes back to the same problem where I am getting themeDisplay null.

Comment: Did you try PortalUtil.getPathImage() ?

Comment: Thanks Devz, Thats solved my issue. Thanks man, I really appreciate it.